# Permission denied in installing Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I need a little help here. I am having a trouble in installing Yii in my phone.
My phone is rooted and I have a terminal emulator and I also have an application that can run LightHttpd, PHP and MySQL. What I did is I use the yiic.php in the framework folder. Here's what I did. I navigate the folders until I am in the framework folder.

**./yiic webapp sdcard0/www/bin**

And I have an error

**sh: ./yiic: can't execute: Permission denied**

I also use the chmod. And change it to 777 and 754 and 764. But same effect. What is the correct permission to install this?

Answer (score 3):

If you try to execute the unix command above to build the skeleton application and get a "Permission Denied" error, more than likely you need to change the permissions on the `/yii/framework/yiic` file to make it executable. If you `chmod` the file to **754** you should be fine.

Comment: What should I need to change the permission? The yiic file? or the yiic.php? Or all the files inside the framework folder? I also did the 754 to my yiic file but same effect.

Comment: Try this : chmod +x yiic